# findViewById in Android kotlin Fragment

Tags: android-fragments

Normally one does

```
  findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view).text = "foo"
```

but this doesn't work in a fragment.

This seems to work, but it seems rather cumbersome

```
  getView()?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view)?.text = "foo"
```

Is it right?

What is one *supposed* to do in a `Fragment` (is it documented anywhere)?

Answer (score 1):

An example of binding views in Fragment in Kotlin

```
var view: View? = null
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? { // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feedback_tab, container, false)
    return view
}
```

Comment: So it can _only_ be done inside `onCreateView` and not in any other method of a `Fragment`?

Comment: make `view` as global variable then you can bind views out side `onCreateView` scope

Comment: If I do `lateinit private var view:View` then it says _accidental override`; is it there already? Or is that a different `view`?

Comment: your view is initialized after you run `onCreateView()`

Answer (score 0):

Initialized your **view** inside `onCreateView()` as shown below:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    var view: View? = null
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    return view
    
}
```